# Im creating app to print user`s repos as a recyclerview. Im using retrofit to get data from github API. Basically, app compiles, bot nothing shows up

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

**RecyclerView**

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RepoViewHolder>(){

inner class RepoViewHolder(val binding: RepoelementBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

private val diffCallBack = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<userReposItem>(){
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: userReposItem, newItem: userReposItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem.url == newItem.url
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: userReposItem, newItem: userReposItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

private val differ= AsyncListDiffer(this, diffCallBack)
var repos: List<userReposItem>
    get()=differ.currentList
    set(value) {differ.submitList(value)}

override fun getItemCount() = repos.size



override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RepoViewHolder {
    return RepoViewHolder(RepoelementBinding.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
        parent,
        false
    ))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RepoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.apply{
        val repo = repos[position]
        urlOfRepo.text = repo.url
        nameOfRepo.text= repo.description


    }
}
}
```

**RepoService**

```
private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/"
//private const val ENDPOINT_URL= "https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos"
interface GitHubReposAPIService{
//using only GetUserRepos
@GET("/users/{username}/repos")
suspend fun getUserRepos(@Path("username") username: String) : Response<List<userReposItem>>

@GET(BASE_URL+"users/{username}/{repo}/language")
suspend fun getLanguages(@Path("username") username:String,
                         @Path("repo") repo: String) : String

}

object UserRepoAPI{
private val moshi= Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

val retrofitService : GitHubReposAPIService by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
        .create(GitHubReposAPIService::class.java)
 }
 //val retrofitService : GitHubReposAPIService by lazy {      
 retrofit.create(GitHubReposAPIService::class.java)}
 }
```

**Activity with List**

```
const val TAG= "Repos"

 class UserProfile : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var userName: String
private lateinit var Repos : RecyclerViewAdapter
private lateinit var binding: ActivityUserProfileBinding

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 //        val binding: ViewDataBinding? = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,     
   R.layout.activity_user_profile)
    binding= ActivityUserProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    userName = intent.getStringExtra("username").toString()

    val viewUserName= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.userDisplay)
    viewUserName.text=userName
    setupRepos()

    lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        val response=try{
            UserRepoAPI.retrofitService.getUserRepos(userName)
        } catch (e: IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "Might not have internet connection")
            return@launchWhenCreated
        } catch (e: HttpException){
            Log.e(TAG, "HttpException, invalid response")
            return@launchWhenCreated
        }
        if(response.isSuccessful && response.body()!=null){
            Repos.repos=response.body()!!
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Response not succesful")
        }
    }

}

private fun setupRepos() = binding.recyclerView?.apply{
    Repos = RecyclerViewAdapter()
    adapter = Repos
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@UserProfile)

}

}
```

**Data class**
I only want two parameters ( url of repo and its description). There is many more information, but I only need those 2 for every repo.

```
  @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class userReposItem(
@Json(name = "description")
val description: String? = "",
@Json(name = "url")
val url: String? = "",

) : Parcelable{
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readString()!!,
    parcel.readString()!!
) {
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(description)
    parcel.writeString(url)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<userReposItem> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): userReposItem {
        return userReposItem(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<userReposItem?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
 }

 }
```

**Layouts:**

Main layout for printing list of repos. At the top of layout we have name of user and below should be list of repos (but as I mentioned it doesnt work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com    
/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".UserProfile">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userDisplay"
    android:layout_width="374dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:text="@string/username"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="547dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**List item**
I would like to print url of repo and its name ("description" as shown in github API)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/urlOfRepo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="89dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="489dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameOfRepo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameOfRepo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/urlOfRepo" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should start by learning to use the debugger and narrowing down where the problem is. Like, are you getting the results you expect from the API, or is something wrong with your RecyclerView? That will be much easier for you to find out in seconds with the debugger than for us to try to figure out by reading all that source code and scrutinizing it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.